# Hybrid APP HTML

Tags: android, ios

I am a total newbie to Hybrid Apps. I don't know any JS, JQuery, PHP etc. I just do graphics and HTML. I don't know core Java or iOS SDK or Visual studio either.

I read a tutorial here which shows to build a HTML for an app.
http://www.mobilehtml5.com/post/371921120/tutorial-your-first-mobile-html5-app-the

**Now my question is:**

1) Don't we need to give any width to the HTML file?

2) Shall I use BootStrap to code the HTML of the APP? I am only targeting the mobile size ... Right?

3) So after the HTML is made how will I deploy it? Do I need to convert it to iOS or Android version? If yes then how?

4) If I have to convert it to iOS or Android version then I need to upload it to Itunes or Google store.... Right?

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at Cordova or Ionic

Comment: Hybrid apps are usually for guys who come from web development. If you're a total newbie, I recommend you to learn native app development. That's way more documented, convenient and way better. My first app was a hybrid app and even if it works, you can't have what you have with a native app. But yeah, you target only one platform.

Comment: Poql, which programming language I have to learn if I target Android? Core Java? And which language for iOS?

Comment: For native apps ? Java for Android and Swift for iOS. But more than a language, you have to learn many many APIs delivered by Apple  or Google. That's a pretty good trip.

Comment: Thanks Poql but I would like to give ionic a try first. Thank you :)

Comment: It uses Angular JS. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're starting out with Hybrid mobile apps using web technologies like HTML/CSS/JS, I'd recommend [ionic](http://ionicframework.com) It makes it really easy to build stunning mobile apps and it's built on top of apache cordova, so the executables can be uploaded to app stores.They have a wonderful slack community and the docs are amazing. Good luck.

Comment: Hello JD, can you help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31996657/error-while-installing-ionic-framework

Comment: @InfiniteMystery If you consider this the answer please mark it as the answer and or vote it up if you found it helpful. Makes it easier for people looking for the same solution.