# Error while installing ionic framework

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I have looked at the other questions and answers but still my issue is not solved.

I have successfully installed node.js
Node version: 0.12.7
NPM version: 2.11.3

Now when I install Cordova, there are some warnings but it does get installed.

After that when I try to install ionic, it shows all errors and doesn't install.

I am on a Windows machine... so I am not using the 'sudo' in the command.

I haven't also tried to install the JDK, Apache Ant and Android SDK. Are they needed while installing?

Please let me know if you want screenshots. 
Thank you

Comment: What errors you get?

Answer (score 2):

In windows system there is no need to write sudo,we can use npm install -g ionic to install ionic framework
Steps to work Ionic Framework
1)you have to install nodeJS
2)you have to install Java and configure it's path in environmental variables.
3)you have to install Apache-ant 
4)you have to install Android-sdk and configure it's path in environmental variables
for reference please see these links [Install Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html), [Ionic frameowrk on windows7,8](http://learn.ionicframework.com/videos/windows-android/)
For any queries reply

Answer (score 0):

Try running command prompt as an administrator before running the commands, that always fixed it for me.